# Can't log in to a session on 12.04 because of Nvidia driver problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I uninstalled Ubuntu 13.10 due to problems with the Nvidia driver and installed Ubuntu 12.04.4 and it has the same problems, but I can't login to the session in Ubuntu 12.04 because the screen does not respond.

Is there any way to change the Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu by using a live CD, mounting the disks and changing the driver files or is there any other way to replace the existing Nvidia driver with a different driver? I think this is the only way to unlock the login screen.

I have been using Windows 7 on this desktop PC for two years without any problem and I do not use the PC for games (special games). When I tried to use Ubuntu 13.10, I ran the System Testing application many times in Ubuntu and it did not report any graphics or memory problem, and when I run Ubuntu 12.04 in live CD mode, the the system displays a message inviting me to replace the graphics driver with the proprietary Nvidia driver. That's why I am asking how to do it in live CD mode. Also I can't login from my Ubuntu installation on the hard disk because the login screen is locked.

Specifications:

- Compaq Presario CQ5000 Series
- CPU: AMD Athlon II X3 435 Processor, platform x86_64
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce 6150SE nForce graphics
- RAM: 2GB

Comment: What is your hardware?

Comment: PC, Compaq Presario CQ5000 Series, AMD Athlon(tm) II X3 435 Processor, platform x86_64, Nvidia GeForce 6150SE nForc, memory 2 GB RAM. Thanks in advance

Comment: GeForce 6150 SE / nForce is an integrated GPU (GeForce 6150 SE, in this case) in a NVIDIA motherboard (nForce, in this case). The fact it shares system RAM (up to 256 MB), the low core-clock frequency and a few more factors, lead to a very poor performance, not recommended for today's games. You may have a hardware issue with the NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE nForce graphics. Was your graphics working properly on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am using windows 7 in this Desktop PC for 2 Years without any problem and I do not use the PC for games (special games), and when I tryied to use 13.10 version I ran many times System Text (in Ubuntu) and did not report any graphics or memory problem and when I run in Live CD mode the version 12.04.4 the system issue a message inviting me to change the Drivers for nvidia Drivers, thats why I ask how to do it in a live-cd mode.

Comment: You don't need the live CD to do it. All you have to do is search in the Dash for _Additional Drivers_ and click the green Additional Drivers icon to open the Additional Drivers window. In Additional Drivers it even tells you what driver to install. It's the one that has _[Recommended]_ appearing after it. Select the driver, click the Activate button to install it and reboot to enable the graphics driver.

Comment: And How to do that, If the login screen doesnt work (locked) ? The only way I was using the Ubuntu 12.04.4 version is in Live CD ! because the normall installation doesnt work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the login screen and login to a text-only console and install the Nvidia driver from there.

1. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to open a text-only virtual console.
2. In the console you will be prompted to enter your username. Type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. You will be prompted to enter your login password. Type your login password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Run the command `sudo apt-get install nvidia-96 nvidia-settings` to install the Nvidia driver. There are three possible choices for graphics drivers. I don't know which one is the best for your hardware, so I selected the oldest Nvidia driver, because your graphics processor is old and small. This will give you worse performance, but it will probably have less other problems than the newer Nvidia drivers. Or you can try first running the Ubuntu live CD and maybe in Additional Drivers it will recommend a different Nvidia driver, either nvidia-173 or nvidia-current.
5. Run the command `sudo reboot` to reboot.
6. If this works you should be able to login normally when the system restarts and you will be able to get to your desktop environment.

Comment: Ok i will try this. Thanks a lot for your time. (Remeber I am Dummy user!) I think the perfomance is not sensitive in this case because I do not use any special games or special graphics software except Gimp, OK ?

Comment: Sorry but this tip didnt work, those were the error messages (I am using Spanish version): "No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes ......".  "Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas: nvidia-96  Depende: Xorg-video-abi-11  Depende: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.99.901)  E: no se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos"

Comment: You have an update available for the `xserver-xorg` which will pull both updates in for xserver-xorg-core and xorg-video-abi-11. So you need to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg` to update the two packages. After that run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-96 nvidia-settings` to install the driver. Alternatively you could first run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to update ALL the packages in your operating system instead of the first command, but it would take MUCH longer to execute. No problem with reading the Spanish.

Comment: OK. I ran the command line "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg" and the problem to login Ubuntu was fixed without change to nvidia-97 driver, then I think the problem was the Installation ISO DVD packcage. In this moment I am working without change to proprietary nvidia driver "nvidia-96". If I have any problem with the screen (too much repetitive) then I will change to the drive nvidia-97 and will report to you. Thanks for your time

Comment: I'm interested in this problem too, so it's time well spent. As far as I know there are only three proprietary Nvidia drivers available for your version of Ubuntu in the Ubuntu Software Center and they are nvidia-96, nvidia-173 and nvidia-current. By the way, you can substitute an older nvidia driver for a newer one and the operating system will function, it's just that the older versions of the nvidia drivers are usually slower than the newer ones.

Comment: OK, I installed practically all the recommendations of the link http://www.ubuntu-guia.com/2012/04/cosas-que-hacer-despues-de-instalar.html and I ran almost all, specially Gimp (similar to Photoshop of windows), VLC, MyUnity, Screenblets, Skype, etc and I DID NOT have any problem !!! then the problem was in the ISO installation DVD with the "xserver-xorg" modules broken (I think) because the installation of nvidia driver was NOT NECESSARY!! Thanks a lot for teach me and for your time. Sorry for my English and for my short knowledge of Linux.

Comment: The applications in the guide in your link are mostly the same as what I have on my computer, except for the amsn, amule, Opera, k3b, avant-window-navigator, and gnome-shell, all of which are replacements for applications that are already included in the default Ubuntu installation and which work better than their replacements in my opinion. The names of these default apps (in order) are: Empathy, Transmission, Firefox, brasero, ubuntu-desktop (for the last 2 apps). If this answered your question, you may mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark to the left of it.

Comment: I generate my custom Ubutnu 12.04LTS and try to reinstall using the recoemnded the nvidia drivers version and noone works, then I CONCLUDED (for PC Compaq Presario Desktop CQ5000 series): the best option is install the distribution installation Ubuntu 12.04LTS (64 bits in my case), no update drivers, correct the problem of xserver-xorg with the comand sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg and... thats all ! I am working 3 days ago without any problem and I used for example: Gimp, Crhonium, Remastersys, LibreOffice, Screenlet, VLC, etc, without any problem and good perfomance

Comment: PD. the only remaining problem is to solve the dual boot, but I opened another question for that. Thanks to all for your help.